# Laravel Upload Image to Amazon s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLpyv.png)

Trying to upload the image on AWS S3 using Laravel8, I added valid credentials but still showing invalid I don't know how to solve this issue. Please help me if someone knows how to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your S3 configuration.
Seems that you have wrong bucket name: `nameofbucket` and ACCESS_KEY: `KJKJKJKJ...`

Then clear config cache:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your reply my issue has been resolved that was a cache issue.